# IntelliJ Idea IDE Community Version ideaIC-2020.1.4 as well as ideaIC-2020.2.3 are not opening in Mac OS version Big Sur 11.0.1

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, macos-big-sur

IntelliJ Idea IDE Community Version ideaIC-2020.1.4 as well as ideaIC-2020.2.3 are not opening in Mac OS version Big Sur 11.0.1
The exact graphical error looks like this.
[![The application "IntellJ IDEA CE.app" can't be opened. 255][1]][1]

Upon trying to open it using command line utility iTerm, here is how it looks

```
deepu@deepusmacbookpro ~ $ /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/Contents/MacOS/idea
2020-11-25 19:53:10.193 idea[15880:147234] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2020-11-25 19:53:10.196 idea[15880:147241] Current Directory: /Users/deepu
2020-11-25 19:53:10.196 idea[15880:147241] Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2020-11-25 19:53:10.196 idea[15880:147241] Processing VMOptions file at /Users/deepu/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.1/idea.vmoptions
2020-11-25 19:53:10.196 idea[15880:147241] Done
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128m -Xmx4000m
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms128m -Xmx4000m
2020-11-25 19:53:10.203 idea[15880:147241] JNI_CreateJavaVM (/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr) failed: 4294967290
deepu@deepusmacbookpro ~ $
```

What could be the issue here?
why is this heap size: -Xms128m -Xmx4000m invalid ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the vmoptions file in the path `/Users/deepu/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.1/idea.vmoptions`, and editing to remove duplicate definition of `Xms` and `Xms` parameters in the same line, the issue seems to be resolved.
IntelliJ community version `2020.2.3` is functional again on `MacOS BigSur 11.0.1`